# Matlab strsplit at non-keyboard characters

Tags: matlab, symbols, strsplit

In this instance I have a cell array of lat/long coordinates that I am reading from file as strings with format:

```
x = {'27° 57'' 21.4" N', '7° 34'' 11.1" W'}
```

where the `°` is actually a degree symbol (U+00B0).

I want to use `strsplit()` or some equivalent to get out the numerical components, but I don't know how to specify the degree symbol as a delimiter.

I'm hesitant to simply split at the `','` and index out the number, since as demonstrated above I don't know how many digits to expect.

I found elsewhere on the site the following suggestion:

```
x = regexp(split{1}, '\D+', 'split')
```

however this also separates the integer and decimal components of the decimal numbers.

Is there a `strsplit()` option, or some other equivalent I could use?

Comment: You can copy-paste the symbol from the file into your script. MATLAB fully supports Unicode.

Comment: That's embarrassingly simple. Thanks for your help. If you wanted to submit that as an answer I could mark the question as answered :)

Comment: Cheers Luis, good catch. I've amended this now.

Comment: @TheSuperLemming Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can copy-paste the degree symbol from your data file to your M-file script. MATLAB fully supports Unicode characters in its strings. For example:

```
strsplit(str, {'°','"',''''})
```

to split the string at the three symbols.

Alternatively, you could use [`sscanf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sscanf.html) (or `fscanf` if reading directly from file) to parse the string:

```
str = '27° 57'' 21.4"';
dot( sscanf(str, '%f° %f'' %f"'), [1, 1/60, 1/3600] );
```

Comment: Minor technical niggle: Matlab doesn't fully support Unicode characters, only characters in the Basic Multilingual Plane that can be represented with a single UCS-2 code point. Characters like emoji that require UTF-16 surrogate pairs are not supported. (I'm not saying this to be pedantic; I actually want to use emoji sometimes and run in to this as a real use case.)

Comment: @AndrewJanke: I was not aware of that, thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 4):

The easiest solution is to copy-paste any Unicode character into your MATLAB editor as Cris suggested [by Cris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59934488/3978545).

You can get these readily from the internet, or from the Windows [Character Map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_Map_(Windows))

You can also use [`unicode2native`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unicode2native.html) and `native2unicode` if you want to use byte values for your native Unicode settings.

```
% Get the Unicode value for '°'
>> unicode2native('°')
ans = uint8(176)

% Check the symbol for a given Unicode value
>> native2unicode(176)
ans = '°'
```

So

```
>> strsplit( 'Water freezes at 0°C', native2unicode(176) )
ans =
  1×2 cell array
  {'Water freezes at 0'}    {'C'}
```

You can get the Unicode value by using `hex2dec` on the Hex value which you already knew, if you want to avoid `unicode2native`:

```
hex2dec('00B0') % = 176
```

Comment: Nice! I didn't know about that one.

Comment: Cheers Wolfie, upvoted for the 'native2unicode' addition. I've marked Cris' answer as the the official answer as he was first to respond to the original question, but if I could I would mark this also.

Comment: Usage note: saying `hex2dec('00B0')` might be misleading: if those first two digits are anything but zeros, it's going to give the wrong answer (because inputs to `native2unicode` must be in the range 0-255; they're treated as bytes). `char(hex2dec('xxxx'))` will work on a broader range of values, because it does a Unicode code point value conversion instead of a UTF-8 encoding conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You can also improve your regular expression in order to catch the decimal part:

```
x = {'27° 57'' 21.4" N', '7° 34'' 11.1" W'}
x = regexp(x, '\d+\.?\d?', 'match') 
x{:}
```

Result:

```
ans =
{
  [1,1] = 27
  [1,2] = 57
  [1,3] = 21.4
}

ans =
{
  [1,1] = 7
  [1,2] = 34
  [1,3] = 11.1
}
```

Where `\d+\.?\d?` means:

```
\d+  : one or more digit
%followed by
\.?  : zero or one point
%followed by
\d?  : zero or one digit
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using split and double with string:

```
>> x = {'27° 57'' 21.4" N'; '7° 34'' 11.1" W'};    
>> x = string(x)

x = 

  2×1 string array

    "27° 57' 21.4" N"
    "7° 34' 11.1" W"

>> x = split(x,["° " "' " '" '])

x = 

  2×4 string array

    "27"    "57"    "21.4"    "N"
    "7"     "34"    "11.1"    "W"

>> double(x(:,1:3))

ans =

   27.0000   57.0000   21.4000
    7.0000   34.0000   11.1000
```